# Obtaining CNContact from CNContactRelation

Tags: ios, cncontact

I am trying to obtain all related contacts to a selected contact.  The way to do this seems to be via `mycontact.contactRelations`.  This gives an array of `CNLabeledValue` with each of those containing a `CNContactRelation` as their value.  There is then a `name` property, but it appears nothing else.

The Xamarin documentation for `CNContact.ContractRelations` seems to suggest I should be able to obtain the corresponding `CNContact` from a `CNContactRelation` but I can see no way to do this in objc, other than searching for a contact with a matching name.  This may or may not be the contact I'm after, even if they also have a relationship to a contact with the same name as `mycontact`.

The identifier on the `CNLabeledValue` seems to refer to the label rather than the related contact, or at least doesn't seem to match the identifier if I select that contact from a `CNContactPickerViewController`.

Is there a way to obtain the `CNContact` for the related contact in objc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related names field in Contacts doesn't store linkages, just names. You'll notice this from a user perspective if you go to edit related names in the iOS or OS X Contacts app — it's just a freeform text field. Those apps (and other system apps) will recognize when a related name matches that of another contact (which is why you can ask Siri to call your mother, etc), but they also let you put down names for people you don't have contact info for.

So a `CNContactRelation` just contains a string, and the only way to find (if there are any) contacts matching a related name is to search the contact store. Use [`unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:keysToFetch:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CNContactStore/unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:keysToFetch:error:) to search, with a predicate constructed by calling [`predicateForContactsMatchingName:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CNContact/predicateForContactsMatchingName:).